# AWS Access Key for S3 user - Key works but don't see it anywhere in the AWS account's IAM users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

We're using a AWS Access Key/Secret pair for S3 uploads on an old client website. During an audit, we discovered that the Access Key used for uploads, while still working, doesn't appear to exist in any IAM user for the client's AWS account. I ran `aws sts get-access-key-info --access-key-id=[old key]` and it provided the correct AWS account id for our client. But searching for this key in our IAM users (https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/users) shows no results. How can this be? Can the Access Key live somewhere else outside IAM?

Comment: That is a bit weird. I don't think it's possible to have access keys without an associated IAM

Comment: It could belong to the root user. If yes, then you very much want to disable it.

Comment: What does `aws sts get-caller-identity` yield when invoked with these credentials?

Comment: Thx @kdgregory that was just the thing. Forgot I was not actually root just a delegated admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accepted answer from @kdgregory

> It could belong to the root user. If yes, then you very much want to disable it. – kdgregory 2 hours ago

Comment: Better option is to ask @kdgregory to write up an answer, then accept that answer.

Comment: If @kdgregory wants to add it I will accept and delete this ✌

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK AWS Access Key/Secret you can only secure and store once you created the IAM user. I don't think you can get the Access Key and Secret pair again anywhere in AWS unless you have it stored somewhere (which is not a good practice BTW).

Comment: You can always retrieve access keys, and you can see them in the IAM console, assuming you have permission. You can't, however, retrieve a secret key except at the time of creation.